# Why doesn't Ballerina let you reassign a value to function arguments?

Tags: ballerina

The following code snippet gives the error: `cannot assign a value to function argument 'a'(BCE2549)`:

```
function test(int a) {
    // cannot assign a value to function argument 'a'(BCE2549)
    a = a + 2;
}
```

What is the reason behind this and can this behaviour be changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign a value to a function parameter in Ballerina. This is by design. As per the [Ballerina spec](https://ballerina.io/spec/lang/master/#section_7.3.1), the function parameters are implicitely `final`. Which means they are readonly.

If you want to update the value of an input parameter, you have to define a new variable and then update it.

```
function test(int a) {
    int b = a + 2;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know you can use a new variable. Actually want to understand the reason why `this is by design`.